# Customize the threshold distance of the Proximity Sensor on Android Phones

Tags: android, sensors, proximity, hal, proximitysensor

For my own purpose, I want to create an application that gives me the real distance between an object and the proximity sensor. Also being able to change the threshold distance which changes the proximity sensor status. Very simple application in theory.

Today for most of Android Phones, when I use the Android SDK the proximity sensor only provides Boolean values Near/Far based on the min range (0cm) & the max range (5cm). 
In some cases the max range can be higher than 5 cm. However, for those cases I have the feeling that the threshold distance is still 5 cm (maybe I am wrong).

I have read that some android phone can provide the current distance. I haven't found those phones yet. *Is it a myth ? (-_-")*

Furthermore, I have noticed that almost all the proximity sensor chips have a higher range of detection than the value we get through the SDK (up to 10-15 cm which is more than enough in my case). I have the feeling that it is wrapped by the OS. 
Can we exploit the real potential of the sensor chip ?

Someone has already asked a similar question but it was in 2012. A long time ago:

- [How to change Android proximity sensor sensitivity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9403351/how-to-change-android-proximity-sensor-sensitivity)

In one answer someone suggested to:

> modify the sensor-HAL to add a configurable threshold to proximity sensor.

I was wondering if someone has already done that on any sensor? 
I have started to look at how to create a HAL library, but I am quite lost at the moment. I am still try to understanding how to create one.

So, if any one has any advice that could help me in my quest, I'll be happy to hear it. 
*Or if someone could kill my hope so I can move on haha.*

Thank you :)